# How to understand Exim log file?

Tags: exim, exim4

Can someone help me understand Exim log file, and also point me a great documentation about it's log.

```
LINE 1
2010-12-05 17:30:15 1PPKHn-0003mA-5w <= username=example.com.br--4219--bounce@mydomain.com.br H=myserver.com.br () [174.120.195.18] P=esmtpa A=dovecot_plain:email@e-mydomain.com.br S=3851 id=4cfbe84724135_7b201579466da9b433988131@myserver.com.br.tmail

LINE 2
2010-12-05 17:30:12 H=mydomain.com.br () [111.111.111.11] Warning: Sender rate 1455.2 / 1h

LINE 3 
2010-12-05 17:30:12 1PPGo3-00010A-FL == super@domain.in R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host
```

Also, how can I parse Exim log file to know which ISP( eg. hotmail.com, gmail.com) is blocking my server IP?

Answer (score 3):

Exim logs message arrivals and deliveries in a compact format, described [here, in the online documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch49.html). The log files are configurable so you can add or remove information using the **log_selector** option.